# Homeomorphism and products

Tags: general-topology

One of the notions that I have read about is that every homeomorphism is the finite product of homeomorphisms. I am trying to understand if it is possible to get a homeomorphism from non-homeomorphic sets. However, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are non-homeomorphic sets and $Z$ is arbitrary ($X, Y, Z \subset \mathbb{R}$). Is it possible to have $X \times Z$ to be homeomorphic to $Y \times Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bof’s example is about the simplest, but there are many others. For example, let $X$ and $Z$ be the [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and let $Y$ be any non-empty finite subset of $\Bbb R$; then $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$ are homeomorphic to each other (and to the Cantor set), but $X$ and $Y$ certainly aren’t homeomorphic to heach other.

Or let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set, let $Z=C\setminus\{1\}$, let $X$ be a one-point space, and let $Y=\Bbb Z$; then $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$ are both homeomorpic to $Z$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic to each other.

Or let $X$ and $Z$ be the set of irrational numbers and $Y$ the set of integers: $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$ are both homeomorphic to $Z$.

Comment: Actually I guess $Z=\emptyset$ is the simplest example, but perhaps the OP meant to exclude that case.

Comment: @bof: :-) True, true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $Z$ is the set of all integers, $X$ is a one-point set, and $Y$ is a two-point set, then $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$ are homeomorphic, as they are both countably infinite discrete spaces; any bijection will be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Is it always true or this is just one such case?

Comment: Is **what** always true? Are you asking, if $X$ and $Y$ are non-homeomorphic spaces, is $X\times Z$ always homeomorphic to $Y\times Z$? That seems pretty unlikely, so what is the question?

Comment: Yes, is X×Z always homeomorphic to Y×Z? How do I go about proving that they are not?

Comment: If $Z$ is a one-point space, then $X\times Z$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and $Y\times Z$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for :-)